# What happened to the rowers during boarding actions in ancient Greece?

Tags: ancient-history, naval, warfare, ancient-greece

My research thus far has led me to the following conclusions: The main methods of dispatching enemy ships during naval combat in ancient Greece was by ramming and by boarding, with ramming being the more common tactic. My question regards the boarding actions, where I've read descriptions of the naval soldiers (marines) boarding the enemy ship to fight their contingent of marines, but there's little description on what happened with the rowers of the boarded ship and what role they played in such an event. The rowers often outnumbered the marines many times over, but I can not find any information regarding whether or not rowers of a boarded ship were expected to take part in the defence of the boarded ship, if they usually just surrendered, if they were forced to row for the boarders, if they were simply massacred by the boarders or any other number of situations that could occur. Are there any historical descriptions or "common knowledge" regarding this matter that someone could share with me?

Comment: Probably most rowers were killed during the ramming or they were slain.

Comment: from what I understand about it, mainly from what I learned of Roman history but also some ancient Greek history, is that the rowers in military vessels were themselves armed troops so would have weapons and be trained in their use. They would likely be part of the defending (and possibly attacking) force. There were no dedicated "marines" in the modern meaning of the word.

Comment: @jwenting But I've seen sources claiming variations of "a greek galley carried a contingent of 30 hoplites and 100 rowers", surely the hoplites would be considered marines in this case?

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't it depend if the rowers were slaves or freemen?  If slaves, would the ship's crew risk arming them?  Mind you, that may not apply to Greek galleys, but it could have applied to their foes.

Comment: @Achi those hoplites would not have been what we now call marines, aka troops belonging to a separate military service with distinct training. Think of them more like army forces embarked on naval vessels.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica no, military vessels would have free men as rowers. POWs and other slaves would be relegated to civilian vessels only (some of which might of course be pressed into military service as transports, but not in combat roles).

Comment: Logic suggest that, both if the rowers were free men or slaves, the winning side would have an interest in capturing them as slaves or for ransom, if the situation did allow to take them.

Comment: It was ancient Rome instead of ancient Greece, but Polybius describes many naval battles in his [Histories](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/44125/44125-h/44125-h.htm). He repeatedly makes note of the number of ships that were captured "with their crews", which implies that the crews generally didn't die during the fighting.

Comment: @Giter - If anything, that sounds like they were considered to be like a carriage's horse team, or a modern vehicle's engine.

Comment: This answer will change depending on the time. Are you talking about Greece in the dark, archaic, classical, Hellenistic, or Roman age?

Comment: @cmw The question is mainly about the classical period in Greece, but I'm sure other time periods can be used to be able to infer an answer